# Java download with user agent from https url still return 403

Tags: java, https, download, http-status-code-403

I tried to download a gzip file from a https URL, but it returns 403. I find some post said the problem caused by lacking "user-agent", but it didn't work for me.

Comment: It is caused by a missing or incorrect `Authorization` header or auth cookie.

Comment: Yes, that's it. @user207421

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways to solve the problem:

1. set cookie

   ```
    connection.setRequestProperty( "cookie", cookie );
   ```
2. set basic auth if the website you access need token

   ```
    String userName = "";
    String password = "";
    String auth = userName+":"+password;
    byte[] rel = Base64.encodeBase64( auth.getBytes());
    String res = new String(rel);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic " + res);
   ```

Hope it works for you.